# posedge clk vs. posedge clk, posedge reset

Tags: verilog, clock, reset, system-verilog

I'm trying to understand the difference between:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
```

and:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
```

Here's what my slides say about that:

[image]

Can someone explain why it's not the opposite? I think the code on the right should be asynchronous since the code on the left checks only when reset goes up, while the right checks all the time (correct me if I'm wrong).

Another thing: I have seen something like `always@`.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> correct me if I'm wrong

Sure! You're wrong!

"Asynchronous reset" means that a reset takes place immediately when the reset signal changes state.

"Synchronous reset" means that a reset takes place when at the time of the rising clock edge, the reset signal is asserted.

And that's exactly what's shown on your slides.

Comment: By "the reset signal is asserted." you mean when it's 1? (not native English speaker)

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

The sensitivity list determines what is clocked and what is not. If the signal is in the sensitivity list, it can make a change to the signal without being on the clock edge, so in the syncronus case, if the reset is asserted, it won't happen until the clock edge.

In the async case, it doesn't matter what the clock is doing, the reset signal will happen right then.

Comment: So the sensitivity list in other words defines some conditions to let us execute inner code.

Comment: There is no 'execution' of code, the code makes gates. Usually flip flops or statemachines. Its really important to understand that the code is just programming gates in a certain way.

Comment: Yeah, if you tell me what course this is for I could get more information on the processor

Comment: we are learning riscV multi cycle processor

Answer (score 1):

Something to understand about Verilog (and VHDL for that matter) is that it is used for both simulation and synthesis, but it is defined in terms of what happens in a simulator.

Not everything that can be expressed in Verilog for simulation can be synthesized, worse there are some constructions that the synthesis tools will accept, but that will not produce the same results as they would in simulation.

`always @(<sensitivity list>)` starts an "always block" with a sensitivity list. In the world of simulation this sensitivity list determines when the statements inside the always block are executed. If a signal is listed without a "posedge" or "negedge" prefix then any change in that signal will trigger the block to run. If a signal is listed with a posedge or negedge prefix then only the corresponding edge will trigger the block to run.

Always blocks can be used to model a variety of different types of logic.

For combinatorial logic and level sensitive latches (note that level sensitive latches are generally not recommended), the sensitivity list needs to contain all signals used in the always block. If a signal is accidentally omitted then that is likely to lead to mismatches between simulation and synthesis. To mitigate this common error, verilog 2001 added the `always @*` (or `always @(*)`) construction to allow coders to write combinatorial always blocks without error-prone manual specification of sensitivity lists.

For edge-triggered sequential blocks on the other hand the clock would be specified along with "posedge" or "negedge". This means that the block would only execute on the relevant edge of the clock. Synthesis tools would also recognize this structure as specifying a flip-flop rather than combinatorial logic.

For a synchronous reset, no special considerations are needed, the block is just modeled like any other sequential logic. For an asynchronous reset we have to add the reset signal to the sensitivity list so that it will trigger execution of the block. Then add an if statement to the block so that it acts differently when reset is asserted. While from a syntax and simulation point of view the "if" is a statement within the block, from a synthesis point of view it is special.

This situation where the same type of block was used to model very different types of logic was considered to be confusing and error-prone and there was also some edge-case issues with `always @*`. So systemverilog introduced new types of block that make it explicit what type of logic the designer is trying to create.

`always_ff` makes it explicit that what you are trying to model is clocked sequential logic. It still has a sensitivity list because you still need to define which clock and if-applicable asynchronous reset line are involved.

`always_comb` makes it explicit that you are modelling combinatorial logic. It no-longer has an explicit sensitivity list, the sensitivity list is implicitly determined (and some of the gotcha's with `always @*`'s sensitivity lists are fixed)

`always_latch` makes it explicit that you are modelling transparent latch behaviour. This is generally not recommended due to it's sensitivity to race conditions but it you must do it then always_latch at least makes it explicit. Like `always_comb` there is no explicit sensitivity list.

Answer (score -1):

Sensitivity lists have been largely deprecated because, traditionally, they used to cause a lot of bugs due to simulator-synthesis mismatches, i.e. if the sensitivity list doesn't match the contents of the `always` block, then it would function differently in the simulator software compared to the synthesised hardware. You have to carefully update the sensitivity list to match edits to the contents of the block to ensure the simulator matches the hardware.

> Another thing: I have seen something like always@ what does that mean?

I think you mean `always @*` or `always @(*)` (which mean the same thing).

This is used to avoid specifying a wrong sensitivity list in Verilog. The simulator now infers the sensitivity from the actual contents of the block and since the synthesizer always generates what is in the block, they match.

The equivalent in SystemVerilog is `always_comb`.

Despite this improvement for combinational logic, you still need a sensitivity list for synchronous logic that uses `posedge` or `negedge`.

For VHDL, sensitivity lists have been deprecated altogether since VHDL-2008 with `process(all)`.